# WPF application crashes on windows 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1

On windows 8.1 if I launch the application by the installer for first time it's working fine. However, if I try to open up the program manually with the 'exe' file or the shortcut on the desktop, the error happens i.e application is crashing.

Also, this application is working fine on windows 7 (on my development environment) and some of the windows 8.1 machine, but some of my client continuously facing.
Attaching the screenshot of event logger.

[image: WIndows event log on client machine]

What could be the cause of this issue? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

There are not enough elements to help us providing an answer in your question. You should reedit it.

But based to my experience of WPF I suggest your graphic card does not meet the WPF's requirement.

You can try to upgrade the driver or check in the wpf's doc if your card is OK.